How to store streaming messages from openai to chat history database?
I have a RAG chatbot where the frontend and backend are running on different ports.
We use a REST API to communicate between them,
the issue is, I am trying to store the "user" message and "ai" reply into a chat history database.
When the user sends a message we can include it to the chat history db quite easily, but with the "AI" messages, the output is being streamed, so, the whole message is not available at once, i am using asynchronous operations.
Is there any easy way to solve this?
I am using Langchain for the RAG service.
code for rag service:
async def arag_stream(self, input: str, chat_history: List[Dict], authorization: str):

    try:
        retriever_chain = self._create_retriever_chain(authorization)
        document_chain = self._create_document_chain(self.streaming_llm)
        conversation_chain = create_retrieval_chain(retriever_chain, document_chain)`
        
        async for chunk in conversation_chain.astream({
            "chat_history": chat_history, 
            "input": input
        }):
            if 'answer' in chunk:
                yield f"{chunk['answer']}" or ""
           

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error in arag_stream: {e}")
        yield f"data: Error: {str(e)}"`

Code for the api route:
@router.post("/message_stream")
async def message_stream(request: Request, message: Message):

    try:
        history_key = "public_chat_history"
        # Retrieve existing chat history
        chat_history = chat_service.get_chat_history(request, history_key=history_key)
        chat_service.add_message_to_history(
            request,
            history_key=history_key,
            message=message.text,
            role="user"
        )
    
        complete_response = []  # This will collect the streamed chunks
    
        # Event generator for streaming responses chunk by chunk
        async def event_generator():
            try:
                async for chunk in rag_service.arag_stream(
                    input=message.text,
                    chat_history=chat_history,
                    authorization="public"
                ):
                    if chunk:
                        # Add each chunk to the complete response
                        complete_response.append(chunk)
                        print(complete_response)
                        yield chunk  # Stream each chunk to the client in real-time
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"Error in streaming response: {e}")
                raise e  # Propagate the error for response
    
        # Capture the StreamingResponse
        response = StreamingResponse(
            event_generator(),
            media_type="text/event-stream",
            headers={
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
                "Connection": "keep-alive",
                "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
                "X-Accel-Buffering": "no"  # Disable proxy buffering
            }
        )
        # After the streaming completes, save the full response in chat history
        async def finalize_chat_history():
            # Wait until the generator completes
            # Join the complete response chunks to form a full message
            try:
                print("inside finalize_chat_history")
                print(complete_response)
                full_response = ''.join(complete_response)
                if full_response:
                    chat_service.add_message_to_history(
                        request,
                        history_key=history_key,
                        message=full_response,
                        role="ai"
                    )
                    logging.info(f"Full response saved to chat history: {full_response}")
    
                else:
                    logging.warning("Full response is empty. Skipping saving to chat history.")
                    # Debug log to confirm saving the full response
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"Error finalizing chat history: {e}")
    
        await finalize_chat_history()
    
        return response
    
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Streaming error: {e}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))

Here, the message that is being saved to database is empty, which is understandable because finalize_chat_history is being called before event_generator.
I tried to solve the issue using creating a new async method to push to the database after the whole streaming has ended, But it did not solve the isseue.

Solved the issue by creating an endpoint for pushing the chat history.
@router.post("/public_history")
def add_message_to_public_history(
request: Request,
message: Message,
role : str,
):
try:
    history_key = "public_chat_history"
    chat_service.add_message_to_history(
        request,
        history_key=history_key,
        message=message.text,
        role=role)
    return {"message": "Message added to public chat history"}
except Exception as e:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))

Each time the output is streamed to frontend, we store the output inside a variable . Then when the streaming is completed, we send a request to 'public_history' route to add the chat history.
Frontend code:
while (true) {
            const { value, done } = await reader.read();
            if (done) {
                break;
            }
            
            const chunk = decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });
            console.log(chunk)
            if (chunk)
            {   
                count_chunk += 1
                outputmsg += chunk; // Append the chunk
                conversationBoard.lastChild.remove()
                addMessage('AI', 'icons/message-bot.png', outputmsg, false);
                conversationBoard.scrollTop = conversationBoard.scrollHeight;
            }
            console.log(count_chunk)
            console.log(chunk);
          }
          addHistory(outputmsg, 'AI')

